# Xpath multiple AND OR operators

Tags: xml, xpath, predicate

Hi I am trying to select XML items using xpath with multiple AND OR operators with no success.

I need to filter where a field equals a certain value and also one ore more other fields equals another value eg.

```
field1[contains[value1]] and field2[contains[value2]] or field3[contains[value3]] or field4[contains[value4]]
```

The problem I am having is this still gives result where field one DOES NOT contain value1 because field3 contains value3. I need it to only give results if field1 DOES contain value1 and any one or more of the other fields contain there respective value.

This is what I currently have (note some elements in square brackets are variables)...
`//item[SubCategory[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),translate('[data:row("Title")]', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))] and Group[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),translate('[session:naroomaShown]', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))]|Group[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),translate('[session:moruyaShown]', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))]|Group[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),translate('[session:batemansShown]', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))]]`

Comment: FYI, `|` is *not* the `or` operator in XPath.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `and` operator binds more tightly than `or` in XPath (see the note at the end of [§3.4 in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans)), so

```
cond1 and cond2 or cond3 or cond4
```

is treated as

```
(cond1 and cond2) or cond3 or cond4
```

You need to use explicit parentheses to control the precedence

```
cond1 and (cond2 or cond3 or cond4)
```

Also, as noted by Tomalak in the comments, the `|` is not actually the boolean OR operator in XPath, but rather the union operator between node sets.  In this particular case it won't make a difference, because for node sets X and Y the boolean value of `X or Y` (== "either X is not empty or Y is not empty or both") will be the same as the boolean value of `X | Y` (== "the set which is the union of all the nodes in X and all the nodes in Y is not empty") but they are different operators.

Comment: Thank you so much. Everything is now working as it should. You have no idea how much this has helped me. You saved me countless hours. I really do appreciate it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct way to structure (and a nicer way to format) your entire expression:

```
//item[
  SubCategory[
    contains(
      translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),
      '[data:row("title")]'
    )
  ]
  and Group[
    contains(
      translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),
      '[session:naroomashown]'
    )
    or contains(
      translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),
      '[session:moruyashown]'
    )
    or contains(
      translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),
      '[session:batemansshown]'
    )
  ]
]
```

There is no need to call `translate()` on fixed values like `'[session:batemansShown]'`. Just use lowercase right from the start.

Comment: Thank you. As with my comment to Ian, you have helped me out a great deal. Just to have this formatted correctly I was able to get my head around it a whole lot easier. I really appreciate it.