# How to fix the #SPILL! Error by displaying only the second value?

Tags: excel, xpath, excel-formula, xpath-1.0, filterxml

I have a column with some info displayed like that:

| Product Info |
| --- |
| I am the 3rd product from 2020 |
| I was created in 1995 and I went public in 2021 |
| I am a not sure if I'm from 2019 2020 2021 |

I have a formula to extract the year in the above column that is:

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<k><m>"&SUBSTITUTE([@[Product Name]]," ","</m><m>")&"</m></k>","//m[.=number() and string-length()=4]"),"")
```

The problem with this formula is that it works fine with the first case, but it gives me a #SPILL! Error on the other two cases. My ideal output would be:

| Product Info | Year |
| --- | --- |
| I am the 3rd product from 2020 | 2020 |
| I was created in 1995 and I went public in 2021 | 2021 |
| I am a not sure if I'm from 2019 2020 2021 |  |

- Basically, for the first case, just return the 4 digits. EVERY time that I only have one sequence of 4 digits, I want to return that sequence.
- For the second case, I want to return ONLY the second year. EVERY time I have 2 sequences of 4 digits, I want to return ONLY the second year.
- For the third case, I want to return nothing. EVERY time I have more than 2 sequences of 4 digits, I want to return blank.

The last thing I tried to add was **position()>5** and that would cut off the 1995 in the second example, but I would continue having the Error on the third example. Also, my list is quite huge, and I am not sure if the **position()>5** thing would work for ALL products that fall in the same second example.

I am not very good with XPATH, so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>**Disclaimer:** Below solution is written on the assumption that when 'count of years < 3', return the last given year. If 'count >= 3' then only return the last year if years come in pairs of two. Hence the use of 'modulus 2 == 0'.</sub><sup>‡</sup>

---

You can expand the xpath for sure if you so desire. However, I'd rewrite it a little bit. Each predicate, the structure between the opening and closing square brackets, is a filter of a given nodelist. To write multiple of these structures is in fact [**and**ing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62970207/9758194) such predicates. To get a better understanding of what most common xpath 1.0 functions can do within `FILTERXML()`, I'd like to redirect you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) post.

So to write a consecutive pattern of predicates I'd opt for:

- `[.*0=0]` - First return a filtered nodelist of all numbers where a node multiplied by zero equals zero;
- `[string-length()=4]` - Then return only those that are 4 characters long<sup>‡‡</sup>;
- `[position() = last() and (position() = 1 or position() mod 2 = 0)]` - The 3rd and last predicate is the trickiest for your query. This is done with a first check that `position() = last()` meaning the node needs to be the last node in the filtered nodelist of step 2 **and** `(position() = 1 or position() mod 2 = 0)` means we want to check that this node is also at the 1st index *or* the modulus 2 of the indexed position equals 0<sup>‡‡‡</sup>.

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.*0=0][string-length()=4][position() = last() and (position() = 1 or position() mod 2 = 0)]"),"")
```

---

Whilst the above would work for Excel 2013 and higher<sup>‡‡‡‡</sup>, you do talk about spilled behaviour. If you happen to work with the current channel in ms365 you could also try:

```
=LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(A2," "),y,--FILTER(x,ISNUMBER(-(x&"**0"))*(LEN(x)=4),{1,2,3}),z,COUNT(y),IF(OR(z=1,MOD(z,2)=0),TAKE(y,,-1),""))
```

---

<sup>‡</sup> <sub>If you need to simply return the last year if 'count < 3' then you can use xpath `"//s[.*0=0][string-length()=4][position()<3 and position() = last()]"` or ms365 formula `=LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(A2," "),y,FILTER(x,ISNUMBER(-(x&"**0"))*(LEN(x)=4),""),IF(COUNTA(y)>2,"",TAKE(y,,-1)))`.</sub>

<sup>‡‡</sup> <sub>Note that you can be more strict about this if you'd wish to validate that a year is between say 1900-2050 or so. One could replace the 1st and 2nd predicate with `[.*1>1899][.*1<2051]`.</sub>

<sup>‡‡‡</sup> <sub>Note that the order or writing your and/or statements in xpath *do* matter. We need to use explicit parentheses to control the precedence. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23992394/9758194)</sub>

<sup>‡‡‡‡</sup> <sub>This is not true for Excel Online or Excel for Mac</sub>

Comment: Nice work with `FILTERXML`! Your second offering is not so rigorous, however. Testing for numericalness without explicitly testing each character within a string is risky: if `A2` contained "*I am the 3rd product from 2020 4Mar*", for example, your formula would return 44989, at least for those versions of Excel which recognise "Mar" as a three-letter month.

Comment: Replacing `ISNUMBER(-x)` with, for example, `ISNUMBER(-(x&"**0"))`, would be one way to remedy this.

Comment: Interesting comment @JosWoolley, amened!

Answer (score 2):

Just add a simple clause to determine the number of returns, for example using `ROWS` (since by default `FILTERXML` returns a *vertical* array):

```
=LET(
    ζ, FILTERXML(
        "<k><m>" &
            SUBSTITUTE(
                [@[Product Name]],
                " ",
                "</m><m>"
            ) & "</m></k>",
        "//m[.=number() and string-length()=4]"
    ),
    ξ, ROWS(ζ),
    IF(ξ > 2, "", INDEX(ζ, ξ))
)
```

***Edit***: I might prefer to avoid `FILTERXML` here:

```
=LET(
    ζ, TEXTSPLIT([@[Product Name]], " "),
    ξ, -(ζ & "**0"),
    IF(COUNT(ξ) > 2, "", IFERROR(-LOOKUP(1, FILTER(ξ, LEN(ζ) = 4)), ""))
)
```

Comment: Great approach, I just have a quick question, wouldn't it be enough just: `=LET(ζ,1*TEXTSPLIT(A2," "),IF(COUNT(ζ)>1,"",TAKE(ζ,,-1)))` Thanks

Comment: @DavidLeal Completely forgot about `TAKE`, thanks! Though see my first comment to JvdV's answer, i.e. you need to account for possibilities such as  "*I am the 3rd product from 2020 4Mar*", hence my inclusion of `"**0"`. And I presume you meant `IF(COUNT(ζ)>2`? **Edit: more importantly, how does that set-up account for four-digit numbers only?**

Comment: My excel version converts `4Mar` to a date (number), If I enter in `A1` the value `4Mar`, then `=ISNUMBER(-(A1&"**0"))` returns `TRUE`, but `=ISNUMBER(-(A1&"*0"))` returns `FALSE`. My understanding you want to prevent `4Mar` to be considered as number. The OP formulated the condition in a way it makes harder to test, to me the condition would be to count trailing years (number), so it can be expressed as follow: `=LET(ζ,1*TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A2," "),,-2),IF(COUNT(ζ)>1,"",TAKE(ζ,,-1)))`I had that in mind, that is why I used `COUNT(ζ)>1`I forgot to add another `TAKE`

Comment: But of course if you first allow Excel to reinterpret the string "4Mar" as a date by entering it into a cell then `=ISNUMBER(-(A1&"**0"))` will naturally return `TRUE`! But that's not the point - such conversion does not take place *in-formula*. Try entering that value with a leading apostrophe into cell `A1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following using `TEXTAFTER` function. Assuming you have years at the end delimited by space. If that is not the case, the formula can be adapted to have additional checks (it is a number and four-digit, but strictly speaking a year can have less or more than 4 digits). Let me know if the previous assumption doesn't apply so I can try to adapt it. The following is an array version, so you can use the entire table column in case you are using excel tables:

```
=LET(in,A2:A4,last,TEXTAFTER(in," ",-1),
 IF(ISNUMBER(1*TEXTAFTER(SUBSTITUTE(in," "&last,"")," ",-1)),"",last))
```

For the case of more than one year, it removes the last year found, and if the second search is a number, then it returns empty, otherwise returns the previous year found.

[image: excel output]